# Using Size Classes in IBInspectable properties

Tags: ios, xcode6, size-classes

Is there a way we can make our `IBInspectable` properties feature **Size Classes** in **Interface Builder**? (Similar to Font)

[image]

Clicking the '+' sign would allow you to choose a different font (size and other properties) for a different size class.

I'm asking because I created a custom view which features a width property and I want to make that width different on some size classes.

Comment: This would be awesome and make things so much neater, hope this feature comes soon, but not soon enough for my current project :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no option for IBInspectable properties yet, but you definitely can respond to size class changes via [UITraitEnvironment protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITraitEnvironment) and [UIContentContainer protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html) that already implemented by UIView and UIViewController (see [WWDC 2014, Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216) to see more about trait collections and trait environment). The font property seems get handled by Xcode just like the constraints or installed.